# Object definition or method call?

Tags: groovy, gradle

In the [documentation/section 14.4](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html) I came accross with the following example of code:

```
task configure << {
    def pos = configure(new java.text.FieldPosition(10)) {
        beginIndex = 1
        endIndex = 5
    }
    println pos.beginIndex
    println pos.endIndex
}
```

It's not quite clear what the `pos` and the `configure` means. I thought configure is just a property, so we can write something like

```
println configure.beginIndex
```

but the line causes compile-time error. And

```
{
    beginIndex = 1
    endIndex = 5
}
```

is just a closure, is it?

Comment: This looks like a Groovy DSL.

Answer (score 1):

`configure()` is [a method](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:configure%28java.lang.Iterable,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) of the gradle `Project` object. The documentation of this method explains what it does:

> Object configure(Object object, Closure configureClosure)
>
> Configures an object via a closure, with the closure's delegate set to the supplied object. This way you don't have to specify the context of a configuration statement multiple times.
>
> Instead of:
>
> ```
> MyType myType = new MyType()
> myType.doThis()
> myType.doThat()
> ```
>
> you can do:
>
> ```
> MyType myType = configure(new MyType()) {
>     doThis()
>     doThat()
> }
> ```

So the manual snippet defines an object of type `FieldPosition`, assigns it to the variable `pos`, sets its `beginIndex` and `endIndex` properties using a closure, thanks to the `configure()` method of Project, and then prints these properties.

It's a pointless example showing how to use the gradle DSL to configure several properties of an object.